# using PURE JavaScript (not library) -> if URL#1 not load in 5 seconds then open URL#2

Tags: javascript

is possible do conditional type

```
<script>
var ON = false;
...
var ON = window.location.replace(URL1);
if(after_of_5000)not ON
then ON = window.location.replace(URL2);
...
more options
...
then ON = window.location.replace(URL9);
</script>
```

??

simply I need redirect (only with JavaScript)
from current_URL to new_URL but if #1 is down, then WAIT by X time, OR go to URL #3, #4, etc...

Comment: You can probably use an iframe and its `onload` event to determine if the site is live, then go there if it is.

Comment: Look up [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setInterval) in javascript